# Две и более функции в таймере

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть такой код

```
var timer2=setInterval("func1()",5000);
```

Можно ли вызвать несколько функций одновременно ?
Типа

```
var timer2=setInterval(ФУНКЦИЯ1 ФУНКЦИЯ2 ФУНКЦИЯ3,5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
    ...........
}, 5000);
```